# Move the "logged in as" box generated by shinyapps::addAuthorizedUser

Tags: r, password-protection, shiny

I used the function `addAuthorizedUser` to add password protection to a Shiny app that I deployed on shinyapps.io, as per the instructions [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html) (ctrl+F for "passwords").

It works fine, but it places a small box at the top-right that covers up part of my app. How do I change its location?

I'd like to move it to the top-left instead, but I'm not sure how to do this other than tearing apart the built-in function and building the password system myself. I'd rather not do that. The unpleasant workaround right now is to add an extra couple of line breaks at the top of the page so that there's room for the box.

edit: this might be built into shinyapps.io instead of the app itself, so changing this might be impossible.

Comment: Can you use a .css file to change the location of the box? I have never used `addAuthorizedUser` so that may not be possible, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure what the element is even called (and I'm also pretty weak with CSS). Can't seem to find it in the page source either.